# sacar una variable de una funcion del metodo getJson

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

El objetivo es obtener el valor de una variable que esta en PHP y pasasrlo a javascript:

el metodo1, aqui paso todas las variables que necesito

```
<script>
  var var1= "<?php echo $var1?>";
  var var2= "<?php echo $var2?>";
  etc...
</script>
```

Digamos que funciona pero no me gusta exponer las variable ademas que no se ve bien

Decidi utilizar este otro metodo2

```
$.getJSON("core/UserVars.php", function(userVars) {
    const var1= userVars.var1;
    const var2= userVars.var1;
    // etc
    if ($("#campo1").val() == var1) {
      // some code
    } else {
      // some code
    }
});
```

El problema es que las variables solo existen dentro de la funcion y debo hacer este proceso cada vez que necesito el valor de una variable de PHP, para ser exactos lo uso 7 veces en un archivo y no para buscar una sola variable, esto ralentiza el proceso demaciado... mostrar 10 registros, con el metodo1 tarda 2 segundos, con el metodo2 tarda 5 y eso en produccion es una eternidad.

La pregunta es si existe otro metodo para traer las variables... que lo pueda correr al comienzo del script, traer las variables y usarlas en todo el archivo .js

Comment: Intenta definir las variables fuera de la función (utilizando var o let, no const), para luego asignarles los valores que obtienes con getJSON (sin usar const tampoco allí).